# Using multicast DNS to broadcast name of my machine like raspberrpi does

Tags: networking, internal-dns, multicast

Raspberry pi has a feature where when it's connected to a LAN, you can find its IP using `raspberrypi.local` ([source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ip-address.md)). It mentions multicast DNS.

I'd like to do this for my own linux devices on LAN, giving them names of my choice (e.g. "xyz.local") how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rPI uses the Avahi application for mDNS.  You would need to install that on your devices.

Comment: Perfect. After setting up configuration as directed in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/avahi#Configuring_mDNS_for_custom_TLD, it makes the machine available at `echo $(hostname).local`!